# in hadoop word count example why not make text also static

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop word count example IntWritable is made static so that it can be reused in the same JVM instead of creating new. My question is why not make text also static?
I made it and is working fine but never saw that in any example. Am I missing something?

```
    private ***static*** Text word = new Text();
    private final static IntWritable intWritable = new IntWritable(1);
```

The original word count example.

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**OutputCollector API**, Collects the  pairs output by Mappers and Reducers, in order to program works properly,  *decide the variable whether it has to be global or not*,based on your logic and type of Application logic trying to solve, In the case of WordCount Program, the program works properly because mapper object is not sharing it's state across multiple threads

Comment: thanks for your answer. still I'm not able to understand. Could you please give me a use case where the usage of static fails. 
I had run this program locally in eclipse so i believe the program was sharing the state across multiple threads.

Comment: Try to declare a static variable in Driver and access them in mapper ..Then you will be able to know the fact that it is not sharing the state across multiple threads